# No abren mis aplicaciones en genymotion

Tags: android, ionic, genymotion

Estoy tratando de depurar usando el emulador android para pc llamado ***Genymotion***, pero ocurre un problema muy extraño, luego de instalar la aplicacion de manera exitosa usando el comando:

```
adb install nombreapp.apk
```

Luego reviso el emulador, y esta instalada la app, pero al intentar abrirla dándole click, solo hace la animación que se pone la pantalla negra, ya que en este caso no tiene splashscreen, y regresa al sistema operativo, pero no abre la aplicacion.

Intento esto en el shell de genymotion pero me dice que el comando no puede encontrarse

Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
Logging activities to file: C:/Users/pedromiguel/AppData/Local/Genymobile/genymotion-shell.log
Connection mode: local host
Welcome to Genymotion Shell

Genymotion virtual device selected: Custom Phone - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 768x1280

```
Genymotion Shell > adb shell "logcat | grep 'Web Console'"
Command not found: adb shell "logcat | grep 'Web Console'"
>>> Failed
```

[image: Intentando abrir la app]

Alguien podria decirme cual o cuales pueden ser las razones.

**Para el desarrollo uso:**

- Windows 10
- Ionic framework
- Custom phone android 4.2.2 (Genymotion)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Pedro, tu aplicación puede tener un problema, simplemente revisa dentro del LogCat y agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Elenasys voy a ver como veo el problema y enseguida escribo el problema completo

Comment: muchas gracias Pedro!

Comment: @Elenasys escribi adb logcat, y me esta generando alli como una especie de codigo que segun lo es un txt, pero ya esta como largo, voy a vr si con el inspect de chrome se puede

Comment: estas a puro cli ? o tienes algun IDE?

Comment: @fredyfx estoy usando brackets, pero igual estoy usando el cliente mas que todo, que me recomiendas??

Comment: Visual Studio Code o Visual Studio Community Edition 2015. Ambos tienen un bonito soporte para ionic, cordova y emuladores :)

Comment: @fredyfx, se que con el code es bien, pero mi pregunta es la siguiente, sabes como configurar el emulador que uno vaya utilizar en el archivo de depurar?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales que OS usas?

Comment: Uso windows 10, segun veo aqui un video, el mismo vs code reconoce los emuladores o el emulador que esta instalado en el equipo

Comment: te refieres al despliegue usando el .apk ?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales he visto usas Win OS 10, revisa mi respuesta, comúnmente el problema es el adb que se resuelve simplemente reiniciándolo, pero para usuarios Win OS 10 revisa la segunda opción.

Comment: ok ya reviso @Elenasys

Answer (score 0):

Usando Genymotion puedes realizar la instalación simplemente realizando un "drag & drop" del .apk en el emulador ó por medio del ADB:

```
$ adb install <nombre de aplicación>.apk
```

Si despues de instalar la aplicación y al intentarla abrir marca error, definitivamente es problema en la aplicación.

Si no marca error y se cierra posiblemente la instancia de tu emulador o el adb que podría tener problemas. **Reinicia el adb!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para usuarios Windows 10**:

Inicia Genymotion y ve `Panel de Control` > `Redes e Internet` > `Conexiones de Red`, dentro podras ver un Ethernet network adapter da clic en las propiedades y da check en `VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver`, con esto podras usar sin problema tu Emulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la versión en inglés de mi amigo @Vilen
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34000567/250260

Comment: Pues el adb lo instale hace como una semana y lo reinicie el mismo dia varias veces, y si se cierra la app asi sin mas ni menos, esta habilitada esa opcion

Comment: Agregue un gif para que veas lo que sucede cuando intento abrir la aplicacion, no creo que sea error de la app, ya que cuando la instalo en un dispositivo, funciona de manera correcta